# Balanced Brackets(stack implementation)

Tags: c

I wrote this code for the problem Balanced Brackets but I can't seem to know why it gives **segmentation fault** in some test cases.
**logically the code is correct because it is passing 50% of the testcases.**
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/balanced-brackets/problem

```
char* isBalanced(char* s)
{
    // Complete this function
    char* stack = (char *)malloc(5000 * sizeof(char));
    int t=-1,i;
    for(i=0; s[i] !='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(t==-1)
        {
            stack[++t]=s[i];
        }
        else
        {
            if(stack[t]==s[i]-2 || stack[t]==s[i]-1) //the statement is correct (uses ascii code concept)
            {
                t--;
            }
            else
            {
                stack[++t]=s[i];
            }
        }
    }
    char *yes="YES";
    char *no="NO";
    if(t==-1)
        return yes;
    else
        return no;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%i", &t);
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++)
    {
        char* s = (char *)malloc(512000 * sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s", s);
        char* result = isBalanced(s);
        printf("%s\n", result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the non-used variable  int result_size;?  Take into account that the loop invokes memory leaks.

Comment: Hint: You don't need an actual stack (i.e. allocating memory) to solve this problem. There is a lazy solution which does not accumulate memory and simply involves counting

Comment: The correct thing to do is to (learn to) use a debugger to figure out in which cases your code fails. Though given the amount of memory leaks I wouldn't be surprised if your program runs out of memory and `malloc` fails at some point

Comment: @wehadarar  This statement if(stack[t]==s[i]-2 || stack[t]==s[i]-1)  does not make sense

Comment: I didn't see the variable result_size. will remove it and try to run it.

Comment: *"logically the code is correct because it is passing 50% of the testcases."* - 50% usually isn't a passing grade, so IMO this is not an indication of your code being *"logically correct"*

Comment: @smac89 you are welcome to post your code. Make sure it actually solves the problem OP links to, rather than some bracket balancing problem of your own formulation.

Comment: The function name isBalanced cries for a boolean return value and not for a string. We are here in the 'C' world.

Comment: You allocate 512K for each input string of size no more than 10^3, and never free anything. What do you expect to hapen after 10^3 such allocations?